# access pdf file on tomcat 7.0 server

Tags: tomcat, pdf, file-handling

How do I configure my server to host a pdf file that is accessible via
`<object data="/uploads/file.pdf">`? I have looked around and found that I should add a context to my server, so within the `<host>` of my conf/server.xml file in tomcat I added
`<Context docBase="C:\path_to_file\uploads" path="/uploads" />`. This has worked in my tomcat 6.0 server, but now the file isn't showing up in my 7.0 server